# How to check $_GET isset for a parameter and value?

Tags: php

Let's say I have a link:

https://www.example.com/?name=john

I know how to do something if a specific parameter exists :

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['name'])) : ?>
```

What I want is to use `if` for both, parameter and value.

Basically I want to do like this:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['name, john'])) : ?>
```

Above is just an exmaple. It's doesn't work.

Can anyone guide to the right code for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
<?php if( isset( $_GET['name'] ) && $_GET['name'] == 'john' ) : ?>
    // some code
    // some code
    // some code
<?php endif; ?>
```

You need to check if `$_GET['name']` exists AND if its value is `john`.

Comment: thanks! exactly what I was looking for!